# function that select ALL paths in folder containing specificic pieces of string

Tags: python-2.7

I would like to use the os.walk method in Python in order to select ALL the files that contain certain strings in their name. Here the code I wrote

```
def func(root = root, element = ''):
    c = []
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
        c = c + [ os.path.join(path, name) for name in files \
        if element in os.path.join(path, name) ]
    return c
```

Now if I type

```
func(root, 'Raman')
```

than I select all the files which contain the string 'Raman' in their name. I would like to have a function in which the second argument is a list of string

```
func(root, ['string 1', 'string 2', ... 'string n'])
```

and it select ALL the paths which contain 'string 1', 'string 2' .. 'string n', but the problem is harder than it looks like. Is there anyone who could suggest me a modification of the previous code?

Comment: Use [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html).

Answer (score 1):

You may use `any` built-in function:

```
import os


def func(root, elements):
    c = []
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
        c = c + [os.path.join(path, name) for name in files \
                 if any(element in os.path.join(path, name) for element in elements)]
    return c
```

Unfortunately, `func` in current form does not read that well. I'd suggest converting it to generator

```
def func(root, elements):
    for root_path, _, files in os.walk(root):
        for name in files:
            full_path = os.path.join(root_path, name)
            if any(element in full_path for element in elements):
                yield full_path
```

Comment: Which is the advantage of that conversion?

Comment: I just realized that they do not do exactly what I am looking for, I would like them to select ALL and ONLY the files wich contain ['string1 ', 'string 2', ... , 'string n'] in their path, while those code look like selecting files which contain ANY of othe ['string 1', 'string 2', ... 'string n']

Comment: sure, change `any` to `all`.